# Replace all strings which matches regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like:

```
<scale_1>0</scale_1><scale_2>0</scale_2><scale_3>0</scale_3>
```

I need to somehow process it to have:

```
<scale>0</scale><scale>0</scale><scale>0</scale>
```

I am not good at regex, I have no idea how write a regex which matches the string `<scale_` with a digit at the end.

I've tried:

```
String str = "<scale_1>0</scale_1><scale_2>0</scale_2><scale_3>0</scale_3>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[<scale_1\\d+>]", "scale"));
```

But this just prints

```
scalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescale/scalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescale/scalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescalescale/scalescalescalescalescalescalescalescale*
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Since none of the answers below seems to explain this . . . the problem with your code is that `[` and `]` do not mean whatever it is that you think they mean. In a regex, `[<scale_1\d+>]` means "any `<`, `s`, `c`, `a`, `l`, `e`, `_`, `1`, digit, `+`, or `>`. If you were to drop the `[` and `]`, and remove the extraneous `1`, your code would work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
string.replaceAll("_[0-9]+", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a replace all with regular expression `_\d` and replace string `""`.

Comment: You are referring to `String.replaceAll()`, naturally :)

Comment: @vikingsteve Yup. The OP should at least know which functions to use, right?

Comment: I would guess so, though I refered explicitly to the `String` method since that's an easier approach than the `Pattern` / `Matcher` route.

Answer (score 2):

This regexp should fit your needs :

```
str.replaceAll("(</?scale)_[0-9]+(>)", "$1$2");
```

Cheers.

Comment: No @M42, the text is captured (with parenthesis) and re-written in the replacement string ($1). I tested it before posting! :)

Comment: My bad, sorry I misred ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `String` class provides a `replaceAll()` method that uses a regular expression.

```
 String newString = oldString.replaceAll("_\\d+","");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

This is a very basic regular expression. You may want to look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("scale_\\d+", "scale");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "<scale_1>0</scale_1><scale_2>0</scale_2><scale_3>0</scale_3>";
str.replaceAll("<(/?)scale_\\d>", "<$1scale>");
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("<(/?)scale_\\d>", "<$1scale>"));
```

Comment: This will replace `</scale_1>` by `<scale>`